# is it important to use SSI in my website?

Tags: ssi

I want to know how important SSI "Server Side Includes" for websites? 
I still didn't find any importance using it. I know only that it uses file format .shtml instead of .html

any comments are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: just a note, you don't need to use the .shtml extension and you can actually specify any extension to be parsed by the server, including .html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only important if you want to take advantage of the features it provides like file inclusion.  It's not important at all for its own sake.  In other words, if you don't need any of its capabilities, there's no reason to use it.

Comment: Thanks @recursive. I thought it is important to use. I will read more about it later after finishing my website.